# Getting a WPF RadioButton to display as a bullet

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

This one is driving me nuts. How do I display a WPF RadioButton to look like a bullet (code - behind)

Using .Content I can have it as an image or a textbox (highlighted if selected). Trying to get a standard radio button with some text

This works fine for images

```
 Dim SortIDUpRB As New RadioButton
            With SortIDUpRB
                .GroupName = "IDRB"
                .Name = "Prospects_SortIDUpRB"
                .ToolTip = "Sort records in descending order"
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Arrow_Up.png")
            End With
            RegisterControl(Prospects_Grid, SortIDUpRB)
            SortToolBar.Items.Add(SortIDUpRB)

            Dim SortIDDown As New RadioButton
            With SortIDDown
                .GroupName = "IDRB"
                .Name = "Prospects_SortIDDownRB"
                .ToolTip = "Sort records in ascending order"
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Arrow_Down.png")
                .IsChecked = True
            End With
            RegisterControl(Prospects_Grid, SortIDDown)
            SortToolBar.Items.Add(SortIDDown)
            SortToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)
```

...but can I get one to display as a standard bullet???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - hope it helps someone else

```
            Dim SortIDCB As New RadioButton
            With SortIDCB
                .Width = 16
                .Height = 16
                .Margin = New Thickness(2.5, 0, -2.5, 0)
                .Content = SortIDString
                .ToolTip = "Sort by ID"
                .Name = "Prospects_SortIDCB"
            End With
            RegisterControl(Prospects_Grid, SortIDCB)
            'SortToolBar.Items.Add(SortIDCB)

            Dim BC As New System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.BulletDecorator
            With BC
                .Child = SortIDCB
            End With
            SortToolBar.Items.Add(BC)
```